# MEAN stack deployment on server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nginx, nginx-location

I create AWS instance and installed `Nginx` server for my project. Now for angular I create `ang.conf` and for node create `node.conf` file in `site-available`. Share my conf file

`ang.conf`

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  IP;

    location / {
        root   project_path;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page  404     /404.html;
    error_page  403     /403.html;

    # To allow POST on static pages
    error_page  405     =200 $uri;
 }
```

`node.conf`

```
    server {
    listen 3004;
    server_name IP;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://IP:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

My node server working fine. I can use my `api` through `postman` with the port for example `http://MY_YP:3000`. But in angular site when I go to browser and go `login` page and click on submit button not connect to `node js` server. When I check my response in network it return like this.

```
Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: W/"5b486d9c-848"
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 09:56:38 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 09:15:08 GMT
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
```

I don't what's wrong in this code. Please suggest me how to handle this.

Comment: The response you shared, is it on angular app (browser's console) or on postman?

Comment: @DushyantBangal this browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer. I have to change my `nginx.conf` file.

```
    events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

    http {

      # Change this depending on environment

        upstream api {
            server 192.168.0.1:9998;
            #put here node.js ip with port
          }

          server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;

            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

            location / {
              # If you want to enable html5Mode(true) in your angularjs app for pretty URL
              # then all request for your angularJS app will be through index.html
              try_files $uri /index.html;
            }

            # /api will server your proxied API that is running on same machine different port
            # or another machine. So you can protect your API endpoint not get hit by public directly
            location /api {
              proxy_pass http://api;
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }

            #Static File Caching. All static files with the following extension will be cached for 1 day
            location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
              expires 1d;
            }
          }
        }
```